# Get Gem name from .gemspec in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm working on a private Gem.  I wish to add a class to the body tag in one of my Gems layout views.  That class needs to be the name of the gem.   How can I output the gem name in the view from the gemspec file?